# Apple Script - How do I check if the bounds of a window are equal to specific values?

Tags: macos, applescript, catalina

I know that the following code can adjust the bounds of a specific window

`set bounds of (front window of application "Notes") to {0, 0, 540, 300}`

But how do I check if the bounds of a window are equal to specific values?

(macOS Catalina)

Comment: I have a very complicated script, and I sometimes get an error, or the windows bounds simply don't get adjusted. For this reason, I would like to run the command again if the bounds were not set correctly. @user3439894

Comment: I also don't want the command to repeat if the bounds were set correctly the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* uses the *value* of the `bounds` for **Note** in your OP to check if the current `bounds` matches the given `list`:

```
tell application "Notes"
    if (bounds of front window) is not equal to {0, 0, 540, 300} then
        set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 540, 300}
    end if
end tell
```

It can also be written like:

```
tell application "Notes" to ¬
    if (bounds of front window) ¬
        is not equal to {0, 0, 540, 300} then ¬
        set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 540, 300}
```

Or using a *variable* assignment:

```
tell application "Notes"
    set checkBounds to bounds of front window
    if checkBounds is not equal to {0, 0, 540, 300} then
        set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 540, 300}
    end if
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to integrate error handling into this code as well.

Comment: @Peter Schorn, There almost always are two things in my **AppleScript**  answers, the first being "_example_ **AppleScript** _code_" and the second is the "Note: The example AppleScript code is just that ...." at the bottom. It's there so the user knows that the code works as is as tested on my system and has only minimal _error handling_ if any, whether any is needed or not. The user has to be responsible when using _code_ written by others. :)

Comment: @Peter Schorn, Also be aware that not all applications understand the `bounds` _property_ as they may not use that _property_, however, in place of that, one can typically use `position` and `size` _properties_ and may need to use **System Events** as well.